# Playing mov-files via Qt

Tags: c++, qt, quicktime

I would like to play mov-files (Quicktime videos) in a Qt-application. As far as I see, QMediaPlayer is not capable to play this format. Does anybody know how to upgrade QMediaPlayer or know a good library to use or any other solution (except libVLC)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

QMediaPlayer can play any format that the platform's media service supports. You should install the right codecs for a video type to be played successfully. Try to install GStreamer codecs on Linux. If you are on Windows install KLite Codecs.

QtMultimedia's implemention is platform dependent (uses direct show on windows, gstream on linux etc). May be it is good to consider using libraries like [QtAV](http://wang-bin.github.io/qtav.org/) or [libVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/).

They work for most platforms and no additional codecs and plugins are required to install.